# Can't set extended attributes on ext4 on fedora 22 - operation not supported

Tags: fedora, xattr

I am trying to get extended attributes working on Fedora 22. I can't seem to be able to set the attributes even on my files, but I can read them. Here's how it looks:

```
[jarek@localhost ~]$ cd /tmp/
[jarek@localhost tmp]$ touch a
[jarek@localhost tmp]$ setfattr -n "user.abc" -v "blah" a 
setfattr: a: Operation not supported
[jarek@localhost tmp]$ sudo setfattr -n "user.abc" -v "blah" a 
setfattr: a: Operation not supported
[jarek@localhost tmp]$ strace setfattr -n "user.abc" -v "blah" a 
...
setxattr("a", "user.abc", "blah", 4, 0) = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)
...
+++ exited with 1 +++
[jarek@localhost tmp]$ getfattr a
[jarek@localhost tmp]$ echo $?
0
```

Some information about my system:

```
[jarek@localhost ~]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.1.5-200.fc22.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 10 23:38:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[jarek@localhost test]$ mount |grep /dev/sda5
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,seclabel,discard,data=ordered)
```

Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong? This works on Ubuntu 14.04.

### Edit

That is indeed on `/tmp` which is a `tmpfs`, not `ext4` file system on my system.

Comment: Are you sure that `/tmp` is on the ext4 and not a tmpfs?  What do `mount | grep tmp` and `df /tmp` say?

Comment: You're right! This is tmpfs. It works elsewhere where it really is ext4.

Comment: And this explains the difference between this and the ubuntu machine - it doesn't use tmpfs in /tmp, just the ext4 mounted on /.

Comment: Thank you very much G-Man for your input. If you submit the answer saying what you said in the comment so that I can accept and give you some reputation points.

Comment: Try something like "attr -s"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t mention it in your text,
but your code block shows that you are doing your test in `/tmp`. 
Even if your root filesystem (HDD or SSD) is ext4,
you might have `/tmp` mounted as a separate filesystem,
probably of type tmpfs, and that does not support extended attributes. 
You can check whether this is the case
by executing any of the following commands:

- `mount | grep tmp`
- `df /tmp`
- `grep /tmp /etc/fstab`

The fact that the `getfattr` succeeds is a little surprising, but not very. 
I guess some developer thought it would be harmless
to report that a file has no extended attributes
when the filesystem doesn’t support extended attributes. 
After all, it’s true — the file has no extended attributes.