# Cannot set file attribute

Tags: command-line, files, fedora, ext4, xattr

I'm trying to use setfattr, but always get `Operation not supported`

In my home directory, I'm doing the following:

```
touch delete.me
setfattr -n naomi -v washere delete.me
```

This returns `setfattr: delete.me: Operation not supported`.

My home directory is ext4 and delete.me [definitely exists](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227448/cant-set-extended-attributes-on-ext4-on-fedora-22-operation-not-supported). I'm on Fedora 25. Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just use any name. You need to select a namespace. For arbitrary attribute name, you'd need to use the `user` namespace:

```
setfattr -n user.naomi -v washere delete.me
```

(see `man 5 attr` for details).

For `ext4`, the `ext_attr` feature must be enabled (on by default). Check with:

```
sudo debugfs -R stats /dev/block/device | grep -w ext_attr
```

And to be able to use attributes in the `user` namespace, the filesystem should be mounted with the `user_xattr` option enabled (also on by default). Check with:

```
grep user_xattr /proc/self/mountinfo
```

If it returns nothing, also check the default mount options in the `debugfs` output above.