# Command to (attempt to) format a disk as non-root

Tags: command-line, filesystems, gnome, non-root-user

I am wondering how to make a filesystem as a non-root user, using GNOME 3 (openSUSE Leap 42.3).

```
~> fallocate -l ### part.bin # Create a sparse file on disk
~> #sudo mkfs -t FSTYPE part.bin # Requires root; how can I do this without root privileges?
```

I am assuming this is possible because of the implications of [an answer regarding accomplishing this formatting in the GUI](https://askubuntu.com/a/22382/39012).

Though `sudo` can give root privileges to only certain executables, I am looking for a pure non-root solution, requiring no superuser privileges.

Comment: Ah, good old PATH variables made me think only root could call those; I didn't even try to call `/sbin/mkfs` as non-root.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423965/30851

Answer (score 0):

Though your `PATH` environment variable may not contain the `mkfs` or `mkfs.*` executables, you can still call them as a non-root user.

```
~> /sbin/mkfs -t FSTYPE part.bin # Does not require root
```