# Create writable file system using udisksctl

Tags: permissions, mount, ext4, loop-device

To be able to test out of disk situations I tried to set up a file-based size-limited file system like this:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file.fs bs=1MiB count=1
$ mkfs.ext4 file.fs
$ udisksctl loop-setup -f file.fs
  Mapped file file.fs as /dev/loop1.
$ udisksctl mount --options rw -b /dev/loop1
  Mounted /dev/loop1 at /media/myuser/29877abe-283b-4345-a48d-d172b7252e39
$ ls -l /media/myuser/29877abe-283b-4345-a48d-d172b7252e39/
  total 16
  drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Dec  2 22:08 lost+found
```

But as can be seen, it's made writable only for root. How do I make it writable for the user that is running the commands?

I can't `chown` or `chmod` it since that also gives "Operation not permitted".

I tried with some options to udisksctl like `-o uid=<id>` but then I get an error about that mount option not being allowed.

Since this should be able to run for normal users I can't use root or sudo.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Comment: Very similar/possible duplicate: [create a filesystem image as a non root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423965)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's kind of mean :) But you can work around:

`mkfs.ext4` takes a `-d directory/` option with which you can specify a directory containing an initial content for the file system; if you already know which directories you'll later want to populate, that would be a good place to start.

`mkfs.xfs` supports `-p protofile`; that probably does exactly what you want to do. A file `myprotofile` containing naught but:

```
thislinejustforbackwardscompatibility/samefornextline
1337 42
d--777 1234 5678
```

where the first line is just a single string for backwards compatibility, which will be ignored; the second line must contain two numbers that will be ignored. (See `man mkfs.xfs` for more details than I remember from the top of my head.)

The third line contains a `filemode uid gid` tuple, describing the root directory. Replace 1234 with your user id of choice, and 5678 with the group id of your choice.

A subsequent

```bash
mkfs.xfs -p myprotofile -f file.fs
```

should do (but your image file needs to be at least 16 MB in size for a default-configure `mkfs.xfs`), so

```bash
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.fs bs=1MiB count=16 
mkfs.xfs -p myprotofile -f file.fs
udisksctl loop-setup -f file.fs
```

works and automounts the filesystem rw on my system (but that's not necessarily the case on your system – your mount thing should work; but `--options rw` seems a bit superfluous).

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of the `-d` option to `mkfs.ext4` and with that it worked fine, I just pre-created an empty directory with the permissions I want and pointed to that.

Comment: Glad to hear it works. I find it a bit sad that makes.ext4 would use that directory's owner as owner of its top directory, to be honest (the mkfs.xfs method allowed me to do that)